# Restore Instance from aws snapshot using ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, snapshot

I have taken a snapshot of instance. I just want to restore it back using ansible.
Please provide any solution, my ansible version is 1.9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `ec2_vol` module: 
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/ec2_vol_module.html

Note: Keep an eye on the options it supports and the version they were added in.

```
- name: Detach the old volume 
ec2_vol: 
region: "{{ aws_region }}" 
id: "{{ get_id.volume_id }}" 
instance: None 
register: detach_vol 

- name: Creating a Volume from a snapshot 
ec2_vol: 
snapshot: "{{snap_id}}" 
region: "{{ aws_region }}" 
volume_size: 40 
instance: "{{ instance_id }}" 
register: ec2_vol 
tags: attach 

- name: Attach the Created volume to an instance 
ec2_vol: 
instance: "{{ instance_id }}" 
id: "{{ ec2_vol.volume_id }}" 
device_name: /dev/sda1 
delete_on_termination: yes
```

Comment: If I want to restore it on my existing instance ?

Comment: How did you create the snapshot? Snapshotting EBS volumes will not reboot an instance or make it inaccessible. However, did you stop the EC2 instance before taking a snapshot?

Comment: No, I just took a snapshot of my instances without stop it. Now, I want to create new volume with my snapshot then detach old volume and attach new volume in my instance.

Comment: Got it now, Looks like you want to attach the created snapshot to an existing instance? 1. Create a snapshot 2. Make a volume from the snapshot and then, 3. Attach the created volume to the EC2 instance. I have updated the answer now.

Comment: Will it detach old volume from existing instance or update new on existing ?

Comment: This will not detach the old volume, but attaches this volume along with it.
Updated the answer, to detach a volume also. Make sure to change the tasks as you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111491/discussion-between-kohi-and-ravitezu).

Comment: We had a conversion and @kohi tried different things to find the right answer. I have updated the answer now. Thanks Kohi.